# Force install Extension in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, registry

Is there a way to **force** **install** an **extension** in **firefox**, for example via *registry*?

I've switched from edge and there it was no problem to force install an extension via *regedit*.

Now with *Mozilla* *Firefox*, I do not even find the folder where extensions are installed.

What i tried is:

- restricting acces to *settings* (parental controls) in firefox, didn't work
- same process as known for force-installing an *edge* *extension*, but on firefox folder in registry, location of installed extensions is unknown (managed to get the id of the extension via about:addons)
- hard coded all settings url's in the windows host file, still possible to uninstall via firefox settings as only http(s) urls work

Did anybody have the same problem and has found a solution yet?

Any links, guides, etc. would be appreciated.